# cfimage writetobrowser functionality using cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

I am using script style coding for components in my application. Is there any `cfscript` equivalent to `cfimage writeToBrowser` in ColdFusion 11?. Or do I need to switch my coding to CFML?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ColdFusion 11, there's 100% tag / script parity.

In your cfscript, all you would need to do is:

```
<cfscript>
    cfimage (
        action = "writeToBrowser",
        source = variables.myCFImage
    );
</cfscript>
```